# How Does Node-Inspector Work

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

Because node-inspector is such a useful program, I thought I'd have a look at the source code and see if I couldn't piece together how it works.  As far as I can tell, the program functions as an intermediary between the browser and an active debugging session, facilitating communication between them.  The way it communicates with the browser through paperboy and sockets seems pretty straightforward.  What I'm having diffuclty understanding is how node-inspector communicates with a node debugging session going on in a different process.

To be a little more clear and concrete, I usually run node-inspector this way:

1. I run my script like so:

   node --debug-brk myscript.js
2. Then I open a new terminal and run node-inspector &

What I'm curious to learn is how node-inspector locates the script I'd like to have debugged and then connects to it.  I've found a "debugr" object that seems to implement an interface with which to communicate to the the node debugging session, but how it initially connects to it is a bit mysterious to me.

Answer (score 3):

Well, V8 comes along with a [debugger protocol](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol), that any application can use.
As the first article states, a JSON based API is used for out-of-process communication.
When you run a node process with the `--debug-brk` flag, you simply instruct the v8 engine to wait for
a debugger (that implements this protocol) to be attached and listen on the specified (or default) port.

Does that help?